# How can I find the ports of a process (Java) in Linux even when the process is stopped

Tags: java, linux, port

How can I find the ports of a process in Linux?

I tried:

```
netstat -a -p | grep'processID'
```

But if the process is not running, then there is no process ID and I am not able to get ports in this case.

I am not running the process in any server, just a JVM instance which runs my Java process.

Is there a way to find the port if its running, or will it be defined in any file then how to search?

Answer (score 0):

If a process is not running, it does not have any open sockets, so it does not have any ports.

If your process has a configuration file, the ports it uses may be defined in that file. But then again, they may not — some servers may use predefined ports (e.g, port 80 for a web server).

Long story short, **no**, you generally cannot determine what ports a nonexistent process would use if it were running.

Answer (score 0):

You can find port of a process if that process listens on a port. If the process is stopped, we cannot know what port it was using if it was using one.
Assume you are looking for a running java process, you can do this

Identify the PID from:

`netstat -nap | grep java`

```
[root@portalserv02 ~]# netstat -nap | grep java | less
tcp        0      0 :::36695                    :::*                        LISTEN      5393/java
tcp        0      0 :::21080                    :::*                        LISTEN      5394/java
```

Use the following command to identify the application

`lsof -p 5393 | grep cwd` and
`lsof -p 5394 | grep cwd`